# How to center an advertisement in a fullscreen html5 game?

Tags: javascript, css, html

How do I center an advertisement in a fullscreen html5 game?
My game is designed so that it goes fullscreen on your browser while playing.
I want my advertisement to be always in the center regardless of whether it is played on a tablet/PC/etc.

So how do I center my advertisement?

Here's my advertisement code

```
<div id="goog" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:10;">

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxx";

google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
</div>
```

I tried this `document.getElementById("goog").align = 'center';` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

change `<div id="goog" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:10;">`

to

`<div id="goog" style="position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%;margin-top:-125px;margin-left:-175px;width:350px;height:250px;">`

OR

```
<style>
    #goog { position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%;margin-top:-125px;margin-left:-175px;width:350px;height:250px; }
</style>
```

and then the html

`<div id="goog">`

Comment: You can't scale ads, it's against the terms & conditions of Google Ads